# Ionic 2 Yummly API error

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am currently building a recipe app in the Ionic 2 framework with the [Yummly API](https://developer.yummly.com/). I have managed to pull JSON data from an online source, but when using the parameters through the API i get nothing back. If someone has knowledge of how this works it would be great.

I search for:

```
     http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/Vegetarian-Cabbage-Soup-Recipezaar?_app_id=MYID&_app_key=MYKEY
```

Response gives me data:

```
    {
     "prepTimeInSeconds": 1800,
      "totalTime": "1 hr 10 min",
      "images": [
        {
          "imageUrlsBySize": {
            "90": "null=s90-c",
            "360": "null=s360-c"
          }
        }
      ],
      "name": "Vegetarian Cabbage Soup",
      "source": {
        "sourceDisplayName": "Food.com",
        "sourceSiteUrl": "http://www.food.com",
        "sourceRecipeUrl": "http://www.food.com/recipe/vegetarian-cabbage-soup-275767"
      },
      "prepTime": "30 Min",
      "id": "Vegetarian-Cabbage-Soup-Recipezaar",
      "ingredientLines": [
        "5 carrots, chopped",
        "3 onions, chopped",
        "5 garlic cloves, minced",
        "1 (28 ounce) can diced tomatoes, with liquid",
        "4 cups vegetable broth",
        "1 medium head cabbage, chopped",
        "1 (1 1/4 ounce) package dry onion soup mix",
        "1 (56 ounce) can tomato juice",
        "3 sweet bell peppers, yellow, red, orange, diced",
        "8 -10 stalks celery, chopped",
        "1 cup green beans (optional)",
        "2 tablespoons oregano",
        "2 tablespoons basil",
        "1/2 teaspoon dried chili pepper flakes",
        "salt & fresh ground pepper, to taste",
        "salt & fresh ground pepper, to taste"
      ],
      "cookTime": "40 Min",
      "attribution": {
        "html": "<a href='http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Vegetarian-Cabbage-Soup-Recipezaar'>Vegetarian Cabbage Soup recipe</a> information powered by <img alt='Yummly' src='http://static.yummly.com/api-logo.png'/>",
        "url": "http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Vegetarian-Cabbage-Soup-Recipezaar",
        "text": "Vegetarian Cabbage Soup recipes: information powered by Yummly",
        "logo": "http://static.yummly.com/api-logo.png"
      },
      "numberOfServings": 14,
      "totalTimeInSeconds": 4200,
      "attributes": {
        "course": [
          "Soups"
        ]
      },
      "cookTimeInSeconds": 2400,
      "flavors": {
        "Piquant": 0.5000,
        "Meaty": 0.1667,
        "Bitter": 0.1667,
        "Sweet": 0.1667,
        "Sour": 0.8333,
        "Salty": 0.1667
      },
      "rating": 3
    }
```

HTML on page is:

```
 <ion-content class="home">
   <ion-list>
     <ion-item>
       <h2>{{cookTime}}</h2>
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

Typescript is:

```
    export class ApiAuthentication {

    data1: any;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        console.log('Hello ApiAuthentication Provider');
    }

    load() {
      if (this.data1) {
        // already loaded data
        return Promise.resolve(this.data1);
      }

      // don't have the data yet
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        // We're using Angular HTTP provider to request the data,
        // then on the response, it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
        // Next, we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.
        this.http.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/Vegetarian-Cabbage-Soup-Recipezaar?_app_id=MYID&_app_key=MYKEY')
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(data => {
            // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
            // and save the data for later reference
            this.data1 = data;
            resolve(this.data1);
          });
      });
    }

    }
```

And my class is:

```
export class HomePage {
  public api: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public apiAuthentication: ApiAuthentication) {
    this.loadRecipes();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad HomePage');
  }

  loadRecipes(){
    this.apiAuthentication.load()
    .then(data => {
      this.api = data;
    });
  }

}
```

in the HTML i get an error of

```
<!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}-->
```

If someone could point out where I am going wrong that would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final code is as below

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of api" [navPush] = "detailsPage" >
    <div class="thumb">
        <img src="{{item.smallImageUrls}}">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>{{item.recipeName}}</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="rating">
                <rating [(ngModel)]="item.rating"></rating>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredients">
                <p>{{item.ingredients.length}} Ingredients</p>
            </div>

            <div class="course">
                <p>{{item.attributes.course}} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{cookTime}}` does not exists in your code. You are calling nothing in your view. You cannot reference a property in your call on the view without assigning it first.
A quick fix is to just add

```
{{data1[8]}}
```

But you probably want to specifically instantiate the `cookTime` depending on the overall functionality you want on the app. so your typescript file would be something like

```
data1:{};
cookTime:string;
constructor(public http: Http) {}

load() {
  if (this.data1) {
    return Promise.resolve(this.data1);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get('url')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data1 = data;
        this.cookTime = data[8]; // or data.cookTime
        resolve(this.data1);
      });
  });
}
...
```

Doesnt seem like a good idea to add this to the load() method either, but that is another question entirely.